# How do I give a new session-id every time I refresh the home page but keep the same session- id between all pages?

Tags: php, html

I want to give a new session- id every time I update the home page and get the same session- id when moving to other pages, but the same session- id is preserved when I return to the home page. I don't want to use the built-in $_SESSION in this question. I managed to give a random session- id to the home page when I refresh the page by writing  session_id(rand()) before session_start() in index.php. I also managed to get the same session- id on other pages. My problem is that when I came back to the home page, the session-id changed.

What should I do to keep the same session-id when returning to the home page from one of the secondary pages?

My code:

home.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<p>Random session ID (---session-id---). Reload the page to create a new session ID.</p>
    <a href="link.php"> First link </a> <br>
    <a href="link.php"> Second link </a> <br>
    <form action="info.php" method="Post">
        <input type="hidden" name="session-id" value="---session-id---">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<?php
      session_id(rand());
      session_start();
      $html = file_get_contents('home.php');
      $html = str_replace('---session-id---', session_id(), $html);
      echo $html;
      ?>
```

link.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "session-id = " . session_id();
```

Comment: Why? I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve.

Edit: also `file_get_contents()` reads `home.php` as a string and not executing it, your function call inside of it is redundant. did you mean to `include 'home.php';` ?

Comment: I used file_get_contents() to read home.php and then replace '---session-id---' with session-_id()

Comment: The problem is that when I am on the second page and I want to go back to the main page, the session id on the main page changes.  I want the id to be changed only when the page is refreshed

Comment: I don't think from server side can be detected if page was refreshed or it was opened from a subpage. Checking referrer header is not guarantee to be reliable.

Comment: One possible method could be to store last opened page in a cookie (or database on server), and if it's matches current page, it means page was refreshed.

Comment: According to the code that I attached within the question, I succeeded in making the session- id change every time I refreshed the page without any problem. @vanowm

Comment: @ShazaAlkharat but creating new session id is not the issue here, is it now?

Comment: No, it is not the issue. The issue is to keep the same session-id on all pages while moving among them and change it only when refreshing the home main page.

Comment: I still don't understand what is the purpose of resetting the session ID on the home page? What outcome do you want to achieve by resetting the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two different ways you can do this (Sessions & Cookies):

### Sessions

You can use session by setting a session variable at the top of your subpages and then check to see if the session variable exists on your home page. if the session var does exist unset it and if it doesn't, then generate a new random session ID.

try this

home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<p>Random session ID (---session-id---). Reload the page to create a new session ID.</p>
    <a href="link.php"> First link </a> <br>
    <a href="link.php"> Second link </a> <br>
    <form action="info.php" method="Post">
        <input type="hidden" name="session-id" value="---session-id---">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<?php
         session_start(); //start the session so we can check if there are any session vars set

         if(isset($_SESSION['page'])){ //the last page was a subpage
            
             unset($_SESSION['page']); //unset the session var so if the page is refreshed it will give a new session id

         }else{ // last page was homepage.
            session_destroy(); //destroy the session so we can create a new session with random ID
            session_id(rand()); 
            session_start();
         }
    
      $html = file_get_contents('home.php');
      $html = str_replace('---session-id---', session_id(), $html);
      echo $html;
      ?>
```

link.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['page'] = true; //set a session var to show a sub page has been visited
echo "session-id = " . session_id();

?>
```

---

### Cookies

You can use cookies by updating the cookie value depending on what page you visted and then check the cookie value on the homepage to see if the last page was the home page.

try this:

home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<p>Random session ID (---session-id---). Reload the page to create a new session ID.</p>
    <a href="link.php"> First link </a> <br>
    <a href="link.php"> Second link </a> <br>
    <form action="info.php" method="Post">
        <input type="hidden" name="session-id" value="---session-id---">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<?php
//check to see if a cookie has been set and to see if it has the value of home
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["page"]) || $_COOKIE["page"] == 'home'){
        //last page was the home page or the cookie was not set.
        session_id(rand());
    }else{ //last page visted was not the home page, update the cookie
        setcookie("page", 'home');
    }
   
    session_start();
    $html = file_get_contents('home.php');
    $html = str_replace('---session-id---', session_id(), $html);
    echo $html;
?>
```

link.php

```
<?php
session_start();
setcookie("page", 'not-home'); //set a cookie to say this is not homepage
echo "session-id = " . session_id();
?>
```

Comment: It works but I'm looking for a solution without using the global variable $_SESSION

Comment: @ShazaAlkharat But... why?

Comment: @ShazaAlkharat I have added a new solution using cookies. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Using cookies helped me :) @RyDog

Comment: @ShazaAlkharat, could you mark this as the accepted answer if it helped?